# Anything known about the growth rate of long collatz sequences?

Tags: asymptotics, collatz-conjecture

Let $c(n)$ be the number of iterations of the collatz map needed to reach $1$, or $\infty$ if it never reaches $1$ (i.e. $c(n)$ is the [total stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) of $n$).

Now define $$C(n) = \max_{1 \le m \le n} c(m)$$

This will be a non-decreasing function (by definition), and if the Collatz conjecture is true, $C(n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb N_+ $.

Is anything known about the growth rate of $C$, both assuming the collatz conjecture, and in general?

Comment: Perhaps interesting: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/collMappe4.htm The first sheet shows total stopping time (in the Syracuse-notation of the Collatz). Your function would be described by the upper hullcurve, I think?

Comment: See a picture in a related question from 2016: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2539279/1714 . If I got you correctly then the blue line indicates your function $C(n)$

Comment: If anything other than heuristic arguments existed, the conjecture would be solved. So no.